# Zend mongo undefined Collection::setSlaveOkay()

Tags: zend-framework, php-mongodb

I've been attempting to implement mongo in zend using doctrine. I've been gradually working my way through the various issues, before being stumped by this:

```
Call to undefined method Doctrine\MongoDB\Collection::setSlaveOkay() in [project]/vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/DocumentManager.php on line 349
```

When searching for a fix, I came across "upgrade mongo to at least 1.1.0". So I ran:

```
sudo pecl install mongo
```

I got the response:

```
pecl/mongo is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.3.1
install failed
```

Leading me to believe I am already upgraded to higher than 1.1.0 (correct me if I'm wrong).

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to fix the issue?

Thanks

Comment: What version of mongodb do you use? Probably you need to update mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes had the same issue... upgraded my local install of

https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb

from branch "master" to "readprefs"

Comment: Ok I got around to doing this again. Can I assume you're talking about 'read-pref-methods'? Should I use composer for this, and if I do, will composer overwrite anything else I have once I've blanked (moved) the original mongodb folder (I'm not sure if I just downloaded and unzipped doctrine/mongodb originally).

Comment: I tried it just by cloning from git (I don't really know what composer does and I'm aware that I brought it up) and fetching the read-pref-methods branch and it worked, so I'll mark this as the correct answer.